# Python - How to return array for a textarea without default array annotations?

Tags: python, arrays, django, textarea

In Django/Python I want to return the words in an array to display in a textarea. The only problem is how I seem to be returning the array, as I have extra annotations:

> [u'[[MY | My]]', u'first', u'sentence', u'[[WITH | With]]', u'a', u'[[CAPITAL | Capital]]', u'[[LETTER | Letter]]']

This is with:

```
def respond_wikify(original):
    wikified = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  original).split()

    concat = lambda word: "[[" + word.upper() + " | " + word + "]]"

    for i, word in enumerate(wikified):
        if word[0].isupper():
            wikified[i] = concat(word)

    return " ".join(wikified)
```

But if I do this:

```
return " ".join(for word in wikified)
```

I get this error:

```
Internal error:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.pydev.parser.jython.ast.Return cannot be cast to org.python.pydev.parser.jython.ast.exprType
```

Which is frustrating since I'm not using Jython, however I am using Eclipse PyDev.

How do I remove the first and last '[]' the commas and the 'u's?

Before I added the if statement this worked as expected:

```
def respond_wikify(original):
    wikified = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  original).split()

    concat = lambda word: "[[" + word.upper() + " | " + word + "]]"
    return " ".join([concat(word) for word in wikified])
```

Comment: `join(for word in wikified)` is simply a syntax error; you need something on the left-hand side of `for`. I guess you're getting Java-esque errors because Eclipse is using Jython internally to test out your code (like compile-as-you-go support), but it's having a problem interpreting the problem and notifying you about the Python syntax error.

Comment: That said, are you sure you saved the `return " ".join(wikified)` line before running it? It should work the same way. What you're seeing in the output is the list (not "array"; that means something different in Python), yes (and presumably Django is stringifying it for you to show it in the textarea). The brackets and commas are of course part of how Python formats lists for display when they're stringified; the quotes are for strings of course; the `u`s indicate Unicode strings under Python 2.x.

Comment: When I run the first code snippet above on the sentence "My first sentence with a Capital Letter", I get '[[MY | My]] first sentence with a [[CAPITAL | Capital]] [[LETTER | Letter]]' which appears to be exactly what you want: I don't get the list format. Are you sure that is the code you are running?

Comment: I just double checked, by stopping the server etc... yeah it worked.
@KarlKnechtel could you please make yours an answer, just in case anyone else has this problem?